# Trying to rotate a 3D OpenGL/LWJGL Camera about a fixed Y axis

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, camera, rotation

I've got a problem with a 3D virtual camera I'm trying to produce in Java to work with the OpenGL binding LWJGL. The issue is that I want the camera to be able to follow the same movement as that from an FPS. By this I mean with performing a rotation around the Y axis (left and right), I want it to rotate around a fixed axis. So when they look down by say 45 degrees around the X axis and then look left, I want this rotation to be done around the fixed (0, 1, 0) axis and not the newly traformed Y axis.

At the moment the current system works by creating a rotation around an arbitrary axis, with the axis given as an parameter to the rotation method. In the rotateY method I've substituted the up vector for a hardcoded fixed up pointing Y axis (0, 1, 0) although this doesn't seem to be working. It just behaves as if it were rotating around the arbitrary Y axis.

Here's the source for the Camera class:

```
public class Camera {
    public Vector4f pos, side, up, forward;

    public Camera() {
        pos = new Vector4f(0f, 2f, 0f);
        side = new Vector4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        up = new Vector4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        forward = new Vector4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    public void rotateX(float delta) {
        delta = (float) Math.toRadians(delta);
        Matrix4f mat = createRotation(delta, side.x, side.y, side.z);
        Vector4f n_up = Vector4f.multiply(mat, up);
        Vector4f n_forward = Vector4f.cross(side, n_up);
        n_up.normalise();
        n_forward.normalise();
        up = n_up;
        forward = n_forward;
    }

    public void rotateY(float delta) {
        delta = (float) Math.toRadians(delta);
        Matrix4f mat = createRotation(delta, up.x, up.y, up.z);
        Vector4f n_side = Vector4f.multiply(mat, side);
        Vector4f n_forward = Vector4f.cross(n_side, up);
        n_side.normalise();
        n_forward.normalise();
        side = n_side;
        forward = n_forward;
    }

    public Matrix4f createRotation(float angle, float x, float y, float z) {
        float cos = (float) Math.cos(angle);
        float sin = (float) Math.sin(angle);
        float one_c = 1.0f - cos;
        float xx = x * x;
        float yy = y * y;
        float zz = z * z;
        float xy = x * y;
        float xz = x * z;
        float yz = y * z;
        float xs = x * sin;
        float ys = y * sin;
        float zs = z * sin;
        float mag = (float) Math.sqrt(xx + yy + zz);

        if(mag == 0.0f) {
            float[] ident = new float[] {
                1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 
                0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
            };
            return new Matrix4f(ident);
        }

        x /= mag;
        y /= mag;
        z /= mag;

        Matrix4f m = new Matrix4f();
        m.set(new float[] {
                (one_c * xx) + cos, 
                (one_c * xy) - zs, 
                (one_c * xz) + ys, 
                0.0f, 
                (one_c * xy) + zs, 
                (one_c * yy) + cos, 
                (one_c * yz) - xs, 
                0.0f, 
                (one_c * xz) - ys, 
                (one_c * yz) + xs, 
                (one_c * zz) + cos, 
                0.0f, 
                0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
            });
        return m;
    }

    public void transform() {
        GL11.glMultMatrix((FloatBuffer) BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16).put(new float[] {
                side.x, up.x, forward.x, 0.0f, 
                side.y, up.y, forward.y, 0.0f, 
                side.z, up.z, forward.z, 0.0f, 
                0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
        }).flip());

        GL11.glTranslatef(-pos.x, -pos.y, -pos.z);
    }
}
```

I've tried disabling line 15 so that the Y axis isn't transformed, but that makes the view very skewed and doesn't show any X axis rotations. Can anyone see where I've gone wrong here?

EDIT: Been playing around with it & updated the code above. I've found the source for the skewed shapes. Solved that by just normalising each new vector.

I can't seem to figure out how I'd rotate about (0, 1, 0) rather than the transformed Y coordinate with the view becoming skewed though. I do want the camera to be able to look up and down (X axis rotation), but I also want the Y axis to effectively stay in the same orientation. In an FPS all axes rotate freely from their previously rotated orientation, however when they look down and turn left, they sort of pivot about the original Y axis, rather than the rotated one. Is this reasonably simple to achieve?

Comment: -1, pastebins die, SO is forever.  Edit that code into the question.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realise. Changed it for the source now. Thanks!

Comment: Are you loading an identity matrix for your modelview on every frame? `glMultMatrix (...)` will multiply the current matrix (which persists across frames), so rotations can quickly spiral out of control :) You may actually want the first call to `glMultMatrix (...)` in your transform function to be `glLoadMatrix (...)`

Comment: Yeah, sorry I should have included that. The main render method that the transform method is called from has a call to glLoadIdentity at the top.